# How can I sort counted DataTable rows according to specific parameter

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I am trying to use `dataTable.Rows.Count`, but sort the result based on a specific parameter.
That parameter being "Column1" in my `DataTable`. So that the output gives me the rows pertaining to that distinct value only.
My `DataTable` is in a `View`, but I need to use the sorted `int` values in a `ViewModel`.

I am able to count the rows with `public static int o { get; set; }` and a
`dt.Rows.Count` in my `DataTable`. I then grab the value by instantiating my `View` in my `ViewModel`, with `int numberOfRows = ViewName.o;`.

But that gives me the total number of rows, whereas I need the number of rows per distinct value in "Column1".

My question is, where and how can I do the required sorting?
Because when I've gone as far as to count them and add them to an `int` (in my `ViewModel`), there's no way to know what row they used to represent, right?
And If I try to sort in the `DataTable` (in the `View`) somehow, I don't know how to reference the distinct values.
They might vary from time to time as the program is used, so I can't hard-code it.

Comment suggested using query instead, adding my stored procedure for help to implement solution:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
    @param myUserDefinedTableType readonly

AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] (/* list of columns */)
        SELECT [Column1], /* this is the column I need to sort by */
               -- more columns
               -- the rest of the columns
        /* I do aggregations to my columns here, I am adding several thousands row to 20 summarized rows, so after this line, I can no longer get ALL the rows per "Column1", but only the summarized rows. How can I count the rows BEFORE I do the aggregations? */
        FROM @param

        GROUP BY [Column2], [Column1]
        ORDER BY [Column2], [Column1]

// Some UPDATE clauses

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the wisest choice is to act in the db side.
Assuming you're using SQL Server, the query should be:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1) AS c
FROM Table1
ORDER BY c
```

This query returns the data on your table "Table1", plus the column "c" that represents the count of the value of "Column1", per each row.
Finally, it sorts rows by the column "c", as you request.

---

EDIT

To complete this task, I will use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
-- Code before INSERT...

;WITH CTE1 AS (  
    SELECT *,  
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1]) AS c  
    FROM @param  
)  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] (/* list of columns - must add the column c */)  
SELECT [Column1],  
       [Column2],  
       [c],  
       -- aggregated columns    
FROM CTE1  
GROUP BY [Column2], [Column1], c  
      
-- Code after INSERT...
```

In the Common Table Expression "CTE1" I select all the values in @param, adding a column "c" with the count per Column1.

Note: if you have 5 rows with the same value of Column1, but two different values in Column2, in myTable you will have two rows (because of the GROUP BY [Column2], [Column1]), both with c=5.
If you want instead obtain the count grouped by Column1 and Column2, you have to declare c as follows: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1], [Column2]) AS c`.

I hope I was clear, If not I'm available to explain it in a different way.

---

EXAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 VARCHAR(50), col2 INT, col3 INT, c INT) 

CREATE TYPE myUserDefinedTableType AS TABLE (column1 VARCHAR(50), column2 INT,  column3 INT)  
DECLARE @param myUserDefinedTableType  
INSERT INTO @param VALUES ('A', 1, 4), ('A', 2, 3), ('A', 2, 6), ('B', 2, 3)  

;WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1]) AS c 
    FROM @param
)  
INSERT INTO [myTable]([col1], [col2], [col3], [c])  
SELECT [column1], [column2], 
    -- aggregated columns  
    MAX([column3]), 
    -- count
    [c]  
FROM CTE1  
GROUP BY [column2], [column1], c
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added my stored procedure to my question, as I am unable to implement your solution. If you would have a look, that'd be great!

Comment: I edited the original answer to reply your latest requests.

Comment: That's interesting! I get an invalid column name 'c' error. I guess I have to add the column to my table and my user-defined table type (@param) first?

Comment: Hi, only in the table "myTable". Furthermore, be sure to declare the field in the CTE with the syntax `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Column1]) AS c`.

Comment: Samuele, thanks for your continued assistance! I get a error message
> Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 14 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 13 column(s).
If I update the UDTT with the c column as well, I get an error message saying column been decleared too many times (or something like that).

Comment: Hi, the UDTT is myUserDefinedTableType, isn't it? You don't have to add the column "c" in this table.  
Please have a look at the new code attached to the answer. It reproduces the "correct" case.

Comment: Thanks again, but I am afraid I am stuck with the same errors. If I do not add [c] to the UDTT it gives me the error I am trying to pass 14 columns where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 13 columns. If I add the column [c] to the UDTT, I get the error message saying "The column 'c' was specified multiple times for 'CTE1'."
As far as I can see, I have followed your solution without errors.

Comment: I added `c` to the UDTT, and changed `SELECT *` in the `WITH CTE1` clause to select all columns except `c`. That did the trick. I am probably doing a weird work-around, if you know what I'm doing wrong, feel free to let me know! Marking your solution as accepted. Thanks alot for all of your help!

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example of your code (only myUserDefinedTableType and myTable declaration and insert instruction), if you want changing column's name?

Answer (score 1):

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "SName ASC"; -- your column name
DataTable dtsorted = dv.ToTable();

 DataTable dtsorted = dv.ToTable(true, "Sname","Surl" ); //return distinct rows
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves my issue (I need to count total amount of rows per distinct value in "Column1"). Care to elaborate?

Comment: @user16600932 updated the code for distinct values